# Which is the best memory option to store about 8MB of sensor data?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, memory, non-volatile-memory

I'm preparing a data logger with some sensors. I want to store that data to a memory. It should store data for a continues period of 2 days. I need atleast 8MB. Here I'm using STM32L053 for my project. All those non-volatile memories are very small in size. Which way i can make this??. thank you.

Comment: SD card? USB stick (via some USB host interface chip)?

Comment: I did with SD card also i wanna do it with some non volatile memory but not with USB stick. Our customer may wants to retrive the data after long time. Thank you.

Comment: Next week the best memory option may be changed invalidating any answer given hence this is why SE.EE does not encourage questions like this.

Comment: "I did with SD card also i wanna do it with some non volatile memory" - in my book SD *is* non-volatile memory. Do you doubt its non-volatility? Or do you directly want to use the type of memory chip that is used in SD cards?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in several ways

## SD/uSD card:

++ detachable.

++ connected via SPI

~~ medium power consumption

Use it with FatFs module by ChaN. There is an example on his site for stm32.

## Dedicated IC, AT25DF641 (8MByte) for example.

-- undetachable.

++ connected via SPI

++ lowest and predicatable current consumption.

You can you it by addressing flash sectors or by installing a filesystem, spiffs for exmample.

## USB-stick

++ detachable

-- high power consumption.

-- Unpredictable power consumption

-- Need to get into USB stack.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a 8M x 8 (64 Mbit) SPI-serial Flash memory ([S25FL164K](http://www.spansion.com/Support/Datasheets/S25FL1-K_00.pdf)) for [$0.86](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/S25FL164K0XMFI011/1274-1097-ND/4457674).  A 16M x 8 one is $1.30.  You can write to each sector 100K times.  If you need more than that, you could buy a 64 MB version for example ($5.90), and rotate blocks.  That would give the equivalent of 800K writes.